# Spring 3.2 mvc, how to rewrite url within controller as part of redirectview with permanent status code sent

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Foo/{id}/{friendlyUrl:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView getFoo(@PathVariable final Long id, @PathVariable final String friendlyUrl) {
```

So it matches ID, and any string. But I want the user to see a string I specify.

```
foo = fooService.get(id); //use id from pathvariable
redirectView = new RedirectView(foo.getCorrectUrl()); //set url to correct url, not that in path
redirectView.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY); //moved permanently
modelAndView = new ModelAndView(redirectView);
modelAndView.setViewName("myFoo.jsp");
return modelAndView;
```

Everything works fine, except the url the user see's is incorrect.

It is (supposed to be) the same functionality as when a question title gets changed on a existing question on the stackoverflow site.

**Edit, now doing the below that almost works**

```
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/Foo/"+id+"/"+foo.getUrl());
```

**But that returns a temporarily moved status code, I want permanent 301.**

is their a way to get both a rewritten url, and a permanently moved status code using spring-mvc controllers ?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov ok, see my upodate I want status 301

Comment: have you tried to return redirectView with the status code?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov thats what the question is! I do that but it doesn;t rewrite the new correct url, it doesn;t resubmit

Comment: tbh I don't get it - should not foo.getCorrectUrl() already return a correct url? Then you pass this url to redirectView and call setStatusCode and `return redirectView` ? why are messing with ModelAndView at all if it's a redirect which is processed on the client side

Comment: @BorisTreukhov no. If the correct string is submitted no redirect is performed and the modelandview is returned, if an incorrect string is submitted a redirect is performed. go to this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089885/lemons to get what I mean

Comment: @BorisTreukhov returning object, ok didn;t know that would work, thanks will try it. I am surpried there is not a common interface for redirectview, and modelandview etc. If you post as answer I will accept.

Comment: OK after I reread I everything(it looks like I'm wrong he-he) the problem is that you must not call `modelAndView.setViewName("myFoo.jsp");` after you specified the view in constructor

Comment: as for the object - it will be exposed to model http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types sorry for misleading info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have

```
foo = fooService.get(id); //use id from pathvariable
redirectView = new RedirectView(foo.getCorrectUrl()); //set url to correct url, not that in path
redirectView.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY); //moved permanently
modelAndView = new ModelAndView(redirectView);
modelAndView.setViewName("myFoo.jsp");
return modelAndView;
```

The call to `modelAndView.setViewName("myFoo.jsp");` effectively replaces the value of View (redirectView reference) that was passed to ModelAndView contructor.
So you should not call setViewName in this case.