# Spring MVC - Handling redirection

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I want to redirect a page in server side (using spring), but the URL should remain the same.

For ex: if user tries http://www.example.com/page1, I want to render content  of http://www.example.com/page2 in browser but the URL should still point to http://www.example.com/page1.

I tried 301, 302, 307 redirects, but all page URLs are changing to http://www.example.com/page2.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089885/spring-3-2-mvc-how-to-rewrite-url-within-controller-as-part-of-redirectview-wit

Comment: When the URL stays the same then it's not a redirect. Just return the view for page2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem of terminology. What you're looking for is `forward` rather than `redirect`. If you're interested you may want to look that up e.g. here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181.

There are at least two ways of doing this:

Traditional, `RequestDispatcher` can be used outside a Spring WebMVC application, too.

```
public class MyController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected void handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/new/path").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Spring WebMVC notation:

```
public class MyController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/new/path");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why such old Spring version?

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is it possible to forward requests to some external site? For ex: from http://www.example.com/page1 to http://www.yahoo.com but the URL still http://www.example.com/page1?

Comment: @SaravananShanmugam - no