# Spring + Tiles. How to return 301 redirect (instead of 302) in Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-301, tiles

I am using the code like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/oldPath")
public String doProductOld(
    @PathVariable(value = "oldProductId") Long oldProductId,
   Model model
) throws Exception {
    Product product = productDao.findByOldId(oldProductId);

    return "redirect:" + product.getUrlNewPath();
 }
```

All works fine but this redirect returns `302` response code instead of `301` which is needed for SEO. How to easily (without `ModelAndView` or Http response) update it to return `301` code?

PS. I found solutions when `ModelAndView` object return from controller but need solution for `Tiles` when tiles alias (String) is returned.

Comment: take a look at this question & answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089885/spring-3-2-mvc-how-to-rewrite-url-within-controller-as-part-of-redirectview-wit

Comment: Thank you. But it is not clear for me what I should write to the `modelAndView.setViewName("myFoo.jsp");` line... I need redirect to the controller. Other issue - it did not work on localhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General idea is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/oldPath")
public ModelAndView doProductOld(
    @PathVariable(value = "oldProductId") Long oldProductId,
   Model model
) throws Exception {
    Product product = productDao.findByOldId(oldProductId);
    RedirectView red = new RedirectView(product.getUrlNewPath(),true);
    red.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    return new ModelAndView(red);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, working solution. But this solution did not work correctly on the dev version (localhost), on example: `http://localhost:8080/project/oldUrl` redirected to the `http://localhost:8080/newUrl`. Do you know why it happed?

Comment: @Escander, second parameter of `RedirectView` construcor is a `contextRelative`, I guess you need to change it to `false`.

Comment: Looks like that it was some cache issue in FF. With second parameter `true` works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Try to add **@ResponseStatus** annotation for your method, see below an example:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY/*this is 301*/)
@RequestMapping(value="/oldPath")
public String doProductOld(...) throws Exception {
    //...
    return "redirect:path";
}
```

Comment: The same issue - `http://localhost:8080/project/oldUrl` redirected to the `http://localhost:8080/newUrl`

Answer (score 3):

There is a newer, simpler way, add this before the `return "redirect:"...`:

```
request.setAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
```

[sic] you have to set the attribute on the Request object.

Comment: which class is `request` object from?

Comment: `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in WebMvcConfigurer also:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("oldpath","newpath").setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
}
```